# D7 Commerce Kickstart 2 Remove the script that call googlesyndication

Tags: drupal-7

In the adm menu, when click on some options appears a picture like banner with link to Commerce Guys page help.
How or where to remove this code from Drupal 7 Commerce Kickstart 2?

Thank you in advance and will enjoy all the help.

ocaccy

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy. You agreed to a terms of service at the beginning of the installation. There it explains that you have the option of turning that content delivery off by disabling the commerce_kickstart_dfp module. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Robert, it was very good! We met in Austin in June 2014.